# how can I implement JDBCRealm for user with different roles in each group?

Tags: tomcat, jdbcrealm

I want to use JDBCRealm for login authentication but instead of having a user_role table I have a groups table which has pointer to the group tables each containing user and it's role in that group,how should I implement JDBCRealm for this case?

thank you

Comment: Question is off topic, belongs on serverfault.com, but really if it isn't answered by the Tomcat JDBC Realm documentation it can't be answered at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `JDBCRealm` for this purpose: you will have to write your own subclass of JDBCRealm and change the queries used for authorization.

Another tip: don't use JDBCRealm at all: it does not scale at all since there is a single JDBC `Connection` object used for all database communication. You are better off using `DataSourceRealm`.